# Can't delete a record with a trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I try to delete some data from one table when deleting from other tables, but I don’t understand what’s wrong.
So i used triggers and this one works  :

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[deleteBankAccount]
ON [dbo].[Clinic]
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN

   DELETE FROM Bank_account WHERE number_bank_account = (SELECT TOP 1 number_bank_account FROM DELETED)

END
```

This trigger has almost the same code and there’s just the problem.

```
DELETE FROM Clinic WHERE Clinic_name = 'Clover'
```

*The conflict occurred in...table" dbo.Dogovor ", column 'Legal_address_Clinic'.*

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DeleteDogovor]
ON [dbo].[Clinic]
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN

   DELETE FROM Dogovor WHERE Legal_address_Clinic = (SELECT TOP 1 Legal_address_Clinic FROM DELETED)

END
```

[image: HowItLooks]

Comment: I'm surprised that first trigger works as you intend, it assumes that you will only ever delete one row at a time; which you should never assume. If you want to delete rows in other tables when a parent is deleted, however, why not use the `CASCADE` functionality?

Comment: Looking at your image, however, the reason is because your table `Dogovor` has a foreign key to your table `Clinic`; therefore to delete a row from `Clinic` the related rows from `Dogovor` must be deleted **first**. Your trigger is an **`AFTER`** `DELETE` trigger, so the foreign key constraint would already be broken. Also, if your first trigger never causes a similar error, that implies that `Clinic` and `Bank_account` have a 1 to 1 relation; so why are they not the same table? Like I said in my prior comment though, you should be implying cascading here, and get rid of both triggers.

Comment: Be very careful about your schema, what you assume, and how you test. A bank account can be associated with many clinics. Does it REALLY make sense to delete a bank account when you delete one of the associated clinics? And does your relationship make sense? Is it realistic for many clinics to "share" the same bank account?

Comment: Yes it is logical that the relationship should be 1:1 (clinic -> bank), thx. OMG, Cascade really work, thats amazing!!!!